# JavaFX ComboBox CSS style

Tags: java, css, javafx, combobox

I am building a small application with JavaFX + FXML and I'm trying to implement some simple CSS to have a specific style.

I have an issue with the Combobox element. Indeed by default its color is grey:

[image]

And I would like to have it white (or transparent), and keep the borders, to match the same style as the Text Field. So I tried to set the background color to transparent but there is a side effect: The borders become transparent too!

[image]

Here is the CSS i have added:

```
.root {
    -fx-font-size: 11pt;
    -fx-font-family: "Verdana";
    -fx-background: #FFFFFF;
}

.normal-label {
    -fx-text-fill: #005EB8;
}

.normal-text-field {
    -fx-text-fill: #333333;
}

.combo-box {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
```

I am not at all used to CSS writing, so maybe I completely miss something out. Is it that the combobox does not define borders? So I have to override the borders and find out what are the borders of the Text Field?

Comment: Have you tried `-fx-border: 1px solid grey;` or `text-field` I think it is in JavaFX

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`ComboBox` [inherits its CSS style](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#combobox) from [`ComboBoxBase`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#combobox).

> The ComboBox control has all the properties and pseudo‑classes of
>   ComboBoxBase.

The default CSS style class of `ComboBoxBase` is defined as:

```
.combo-box-base {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-shadow-highlight-color, -fx-outer-border, -fx-inner-border, -fx-body-color;
    -fx-background-insets: 0 0 -1 0, 0, 1, 2;
    -fx-background-radius: 3px, 3px, 2px, 1px;
    -fx-padding: 0.333333em 0.666667em 0.333333em 0.666667em; /* 4 8 4 8 */
    -fx-text-fill: -fx-text-base-color;
    -fx-alignment: CENTER;
    -fx-content-display: LEFT;
}
```

You can overwrite this style class like:

```
.combo-box-base {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-shadow-highlight-color, -fx-outer-border, -fx-inner-border, white;
    -fx-background-insets: 0 0 -1 0, 0, 1, 2;
    -fx-background-radius: 3px, 3px, 2px, 1px;
}
```

This style-class just sets the inner part to white, the border is actually untouched (remove the last two properties and then you will get a plain white borderless `ComboBox`).

---

**Note:**

Overwriting `.combo-box-base` or `.combo-box` style-classes are equivalent if only `ComboBox`es are used.

The reason in the answer to use `.combo-box-base` style-class rather than the other one is that there are other controls inheriting also the `.combo-box-base` style-class, such as [`ColorPicker`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#colorpicker) and [`DatePicker`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/DatePicker.html). Overwriting `.combo-box-base` yields in having all these controls sharing the same style, resulting in a much unified design.

Comment: Will try! I was thinking that I could override the - fx-body-color as well,  but I suppose it is used in a lot of UI controls...

Comment: Works like a charm :) Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can add the following properties to control the border:

```
-fx-border-color: #D3D3D3
-fx-border-width: 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: So basically overriding the borders in the definition to have them printed,  but normally sure they would be displayed the same way as for text field?