# How to change resting text color on javafx ComboBox

Tags: java, css, javafx, combobox

I am writing a javafx app that uses css to create a custom look for the entire app. I don't like using external css files so all my styling is done through calls to setStyle for various nodes. I am trying to customize a comboBox and have run into some issues. I have figured out how to style the actual dropdown list using the cell factory, but after hours of googling I haven't been able to figure out how I can change the text color of the combobox when it is just sitting there on the screen. Here is a picture for an example:

[image]

As you can see, my list is styled fine, but the "true" being displayed by the box itself is still the default gray color. I want it to be white, but can't find any examples on how to achieve this. All help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: take a look at the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38440944/6561404 see if that helps you.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html#buttonCellProperty